# Modify view showing style options in French

Tags: 2013, language

I just created a new SharePoint 2013 site. Everything on the site is in English, EXCEPT the Style option in Modify View shows these options (I presume they are in French):

```
Tableau de base
Encadré, pas d'étiquette
Encadré
Bulletin d'informations
Bulletin d'informations, pas de ligne
Ombré
Volet Aperçu
Default
```

I have Regional Settings set to English (United States), as well as My Settings. I have tried changed them back and forth to see if this fixes the problem, no luck.

Comment: C'est estrange, non? Is that same section showing French on other sites within the farm or just on this one?

Comment: This is my first site collection with this hosting company, so I don't know. It is consistent across all lists.

Comment: It was normal again last night, first thing this morning, it's in Italian.

Comment: You should definitely check with the hoster - it sounds like a problem with the template behind the site.